Is it possible to select those misclassified samples by SVM that are farthest from the hyperplane?
I am working in R with an SVM model from the e1071 library, and my question is whether I can identify those samples that the model has misclassified and are farthest from the SVM hyperplane.
My code is as follows:
best_model <- list(
    model = svm(x = omicDataReduced[, -which(colnames(omicDataReduced) == classVariable)],
                y = omicDataReduced[[classVariable]],
                kernel = best_kernel,
                cost = best_C,
                probability = TRUE,
                decision.values = TRUE),
    error = best_error,
    cost = best_C,
    kernel = best_kernel
  )

My dataset has 790 samples and 18,710 predictors.
Edit:
I have discovered that with the 'decision.values' attribute, you can get the distance to the hyperplane. My question now is: How can I check that the samples are beyond the margins?
Here's the code I have so far:
pred <- predict(best_model$model, omicDataReduced[, -which(colnames(omicDataReduced) == classVariable)], decision.value=T)

  decision_values <- attr(pred, "decision.values")

  misclassified_indices <- which(as.numeric(pred) != as.numeric(omicDataReduced[[classVariable]]))

  misclassified_decision_values <- abs(decision_values[misclassified_indices])

  selected_indices <- misclassified_indices[order(misclassified_decision_values, decreasing = TRUE)][1:round(diagnosticChangeProbability * length(misclassified_indices))]


You can obtain the distance of an observation from a (or the, if you have only two classes) hyperplane like so: dv <- attr(predict(model, x, decision.values = TRUE), "decision.values"). The matrix of decision values (here: dv) is conveniently labelled with the classes separated by the respective column(s).

Yes, but is that distance proportional to the value of model$epsilon? In other words, if a sample has a decision value of -1.05 and model$epsilon is 0.1, does that mean it is beyond the margin defined svm or not?

Do you want to identify misclassifications (like with: table(fitted(model), omicDataReduced[[classVariable]]))?

I would like to know which misclassified points are outside the margins defined by the SVM.
